# How to see the logs printed by NSLogs used in a dynamic framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, console, ios10, nslog

The app uses a c++ library that was built as a dynamic framework. I am not able to see the logs from the framework, at the device console (the console to see the logs for deployed applications, not the xcode debug console) for app running on iOS 10.x. I could see the logs for the same app running on iOS 9.x.

I tried replacing NSLog at runtime with a custom logger using a macro. Though it works for the app code, it does not work for the the code within library framework. Is there a way to replace NSLog using a macro that works for external framework as well, without modifying the library code?

If I had to absolutely modify the library code to replace the NSLogs, What should I replace it with, so it shows on the device console for deployed apps?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to replace NSLog using a macro that works for external
>   framework as well, without modifying the library code?

I could not find any way to do that, as it was compiled already.

> If I had to absolutely modify the library code to replace the NSLogs,
>   What should I replace it with, so it shows on the device console for
>   deployed apps?

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:10.0 options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, formattedMsg);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%s", formattedMsg);
}
```

Using OS_LOG_DEFAULT, made the logs visibility same as system logs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the co-founder of a product called [Bugfender](http://bugfender.com) that might help you, we have an SDK that provides a function to replace NSLog and that it sends logs to our server.

We have a dynamic framework version of this SDK that you might be able to integrate in your library to get the logs of it.

Our SDK will work while doing development or once the app is release to the store.